# How to properly enforce a conditional read-only record on Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, validation, activerecord

So a situation came up at work and I wanted to discuss it here because we could not get to an agreement between us:

We have two models, `Order` and `Passport`, which are related in a way that an Order has_one passport and a passport has_many orders. Whenever an order is completed, its associated passport must be 'locked', that is, turned into read-only (that information was already used to clear customs, so it can't be changed afterwards). We want to enforce that rule in the `Passport` model and we've thought of the following options:

1. **Creating a validation**. CONS: There will be records yielding `valid? => false` when technically the record is fine (although it can't be saved). For example, if other records have a `validates_associated :passport` on them, that could be a problem.
2. **Overriding the `readonly?` method**. CONS: This will raise an exception when trying to update that record, although you would expect that calling a `save` method won't ever raise one.
3. **Creating a `before_save` callback**. This has two flavors: either raise an exception (which is pretty much like the `readonly?` option) or add an `@error` and return `false` to stop the callback chain. CONS: Adding validation errors from outside a proper validation can be considered a bad practice. Also, you might find yourself calling `valid?` and getting `true` and then call `save` and get `false`.

This situation made us think a lot about the relationship between validations and Rails. What exactly does it mean for a record to be `valid?`? Does it imply that the `save` will work?

I would like to listen to your opinions to learn about this scenario. Maybe the best approach is neither one of the three! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

What about marking this record as read-only by using `readonly!` instance method? See the [API](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Base/readonly%21)

You could do it in a constructor, like:

```
class Passport < ActiveRecord::Base
  def initialize(*args)
    super(*args)
    readonly! if orders.count>0 # or similar
  end
end
```

Comment: I think that will fail if the passport object is initialized before the order's update.

Comment: Isn't that pretty much the same behavior as overriding the `readonly?` method? I mean, what will happen when trying to `save` the record? An exception?

Comment: Yes, an exception `ActiveRecord::ReadOnlyRecord`

Answer (score 0):

I think there is an extra alternative. What you describe dictates that the `Passport` model can have some different states. I would consider using a state machine to describe the relevant orders status for the passport.

eg:

- open
- pending
- locked
- other_update_actions ...

With that in mind, all relevant order actions will trigger an event to the passport model and its state.

If it is possible to integrate the update actions to certain events then you could handle the readonly part in a more elegant way (incompatible state transition).

As an extra check you can always keep an *ugly* validator as a last resort to prevent the model from being updated without the state machine.

you can check [the aasm gem](https://github.com/aasm/aasm) for this